# WIX non admin Installation

Tags: c#, winforms, wix

I have an issue regarding wix setup generation, here is my scenario

I have created a setup and tried to install on completion of installation I have done code to create a key in HKCU(H key current user), upto here it is fine.

Now if I try to install with non admin rights then it asked for admin password, then I have entered, installation is completed, problem is the key which I tried to insert in HKCU (Current User) is inserted into the admin account not in the current account where I am installing.

FYI
I am using C# winforms and WIX to generate setup

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Kind Regards,,
Raghu.M.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply,

This is the way, I approached to solve this.

I have created a component where it inserts key in Local Machine Which will be common for all, and thereby proceed further.

Kind Regards,
Raghu.M

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installer that can be executed by non-administrator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358274/129269

As mentioned you can no longer install things that require elevated privileges. But on the other hand, when trying to add values to the HKCU my guess is you don't want to install system wide resources.

Answer (score 0):

Update your application to write the default HKCU registry data on first launch. It is much easier than having your setup do the job.

For a description on how you can manage HKCU values after they have been written - in case they need modification, deletion or changing during a reinstall of the application - you can check this thread: http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21552