# How can I create a windows installer MSI that does not require admin access using setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

this question helped me create an MSI file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/256664/is-it-possible-to-create-a-setup-filemsi-in-visual.html
Now, how do i create an installer that doesn't require admin access?

Comment: you think it's wise for a system to allow _non-admins_ to install software?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I have to create an MSI installer which gets installed for standard users in my organization without entering admin credentials, is this possible? if yes, how can i create such msi? thank you.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/7bt5jb/allowing_a_single_msi_to_be_installed_wo_admin/

Comment: a better solution might be to roll out the msi via the domain - ask your local windows network admin for help

Comment: @absolutealgorithm One of the approaches would be to use WiX toolset instead of the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Setup project and use [non-Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358274/8607180) install.

Comment: you can try to install your MSI in per user mode by setting the 2 properties ALLUSERS and MSIINSTALLPERUSER :
`msiexec /i "package.msi" ALLUSERS=2 MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`

Comment: I will try to do it with the help of WiX toolset and get back to you guys, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The **Windows Installer project** will create a MSI file where the user is allowed to select the install type, per-user or per-machine during installation.

The Windows Installer performs a per-user installation or per-machine installation depending the value of the **ALLUSERS** property, the value of the **MSIINSTALLPERUSER** property and the version of the operating system.

The value of the **ALLUSERS** property, at installation time, determines the installation context.

An **ALLUSERS** property value of **1** specifies the **per-machine** installation context.

An **ALLUSERS** property value of an empty string ("") specifies the **per-user** installation context.

So, in the **Windows Installer project** you need to define the ALLUSERS property to an empty string so that **per-user** installation be made. Please make sure that the resulted installer does not contain any registries created on the HKLM or does not install any file in locations that would require admin privileges (e.g. ProgramFiles). Since the installer does not have admin privileges, the installation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer***: MSI is an old technology, and its implementation of per-user (non-admin setups) is not ideal (**`severe technical limitations / restrictions`**, **`poor servicing for patching and upgrades`**, **`etc...`**). I would recommend to use some other deployment mechanism such as [MSIX or AppV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130).

---

***Non-Admin MSI / Per-User MSI***: Nonetheless, here are some comments on the topic of per user installations and an example made using WiX:

- ***WiX Sample***: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXPerUserSample
- [On the topic of per-user MSI installations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266302/129130) (how-to, difficulties and peculiarities)

  - [Having an issue with WIX upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841856/having-an-issue-with-wix-upgrade/29843248#29843248)
  - [Understanding “Per-User” or “Per-Machine” context for application Setup packages](https://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/understanding-per-user-or-per-machine-context-for-application-setup-packages/)
  - [You must adhere to a number of restrictions for the MSI](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-package.html)